# Array Parameter value not getting in jasperserver

Tags: php, arrays, jasperserver

i am using `jasperserver`. Below is my `PHP` `jasper server` url

```
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/projects/crm_extra_work.pdf?customer_id=7704&query%5B0%5D=29&query%5B1%5D=32
```

From that the parameter `query` is array . But the `jasperserver` getting `NULL` value. What is the problem in that?

i tried `query[]=29&query[]=32` and `query[0]=29&query[1]=32` but no Use..

Comment: Try to use: `&query=29&query=32`

Comment: Another way is to pass a values separated with comma, for example

Comment: How to pass using Comma?

Comment: Not working.. Is there any input control settings in jasperserver?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/projects/crm_extra_work.pdf?customer_id=7704&query=29&query=32.. Try this without [ ] this.